# Sudden crash due to firebase not accepting my object

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I had this code running for the past month and it was fine. I dont believe i changed anything that should have affected it but now when I run it I get an error saying that firebase doesn't accept this kind of object. Here is my code:

```
 var postId = ""
func UploadPost(){
    let FirstName = LoggedIn.User["First Name"] as! String
    let LastName = LoggedIn.User["Last Name"] as! String
    let posterId = LoggedIn.User["UserID"] as! String
    let Name = FirstName + " " + LastName

    let Epoch = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
    let Title = PostTitle.text
    let Posting = Post.text
    self.postId = UUID().uuidString

    if(Title != nil && Posting != nil){
        let Post = [
            "Post": Posting!,
            "PostTitle": Title!,
            "Poster": Name,
            "Epoch": Epoch,
            "Username": self.user,
            "PostId": self.postId,
            "PosterId": posterId
            ] as [String : Any]
        PostData(newPostData: Post){(success, error) in
            guard success else{
                let BadPostRequest = Banner.ErrorBanner(errorTitle: "Could not write post.")
                BadPostRequest.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(1)
                self.view.addSubview(BadPostRequest)
                GenericTools.Logger(data: "\n Could not write post: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating();
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents();
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
func PostData(newPostData: Dictionary<String, Any>, completion: @escaping (Bool, Error?) -> Void){
    let v = postId
    Database.database().reference().child("Forum").child(self.postId).setValue(newPostData){ error in
        completion(false, error)
    }

    Database.database().reference().child("Forum/ForumIds").child(self.postId).setValue(self.postId){ error in
        completion(false, error)
    }
    completion(true, nil)
}
```

Error:

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidFirebaseData', reason: '(nodeFrom:priority:) Cannot store object of type _SwiftValue at . Can only store objects of type NSNumber, NSString, NSDictionary, and NSArray.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184777d38 0x183c8c528 0x104ed013c 0x104ecf6c4 0x104ecf5f8 0x104ecf4e4 0x104ecf80c 0x104ecf6c4 0x104ecf5f8 0x104eb013c 0x104eaffd0 0x104db0dfc 0x104db02b0 0x104dac4e4 0x104dac678 0x18dbbc20c 0x18dbbc18c 0x18dba6f4c 0x18dbbba80 0x18dbbb5a0 0x18dbb6a70 0x18db88078 0x18e4c7f98 0x18e4ca408 0x18e4c3574 0x184720358 0x1847202d8 0x18471fb60 0x18471d738 0x18463e2d8 0x1864cff84 0x18dbeb880 0x104d7f734 0x18416256c)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: You've kinda opened yourself up to this error by defining properties as String: Any... i.e. Firebase doesn't except Any, it only accepts 4 object types as values. To answer we would need more specific data about what some of the properties are/contain. However, *"Username": self.user,* is very suspicious. In the future, you may want to error trap your code or lock it down so you don't inadvertently pass something to firebase that's not valid.

Comment: Good catch on `self.user` Jay!